# ColdFusion 9 CFScript Private Properties and Public Properties

Tags: oop, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

Is there a way to make isDevMode, devModeToEmailAddress, devModeFromEmailAddress to be private properites?

Code:

```
/**
* email
* @accessors true
*/
component email output="false" hint="This is email object." {

/* properties */
property name="toEmailAddress"   type="string";
property name="fromEmailAddress" type="string";
property name="subject"          type="string";
property name="body"             type="string";
property name="attachments"      type="array";

/*
private isDevMode
private devModeToEmailAddress
private devModeFromEmailAddress
*/

}
```

Comment: What is your intention? Properties (among other things) define accessors in CF, which implies that they should be available to access (and therefore, not private). Are you attempting to enforce a relational mapping to private variables in the ORM? Or, do you "just want some private vars"--if the latter, you'll want to set them in the 'variables' scope.

Comment: I am not using ORM I simply would like properties that can be set only inside the object and not by something outside the object.  This way if the website is in devmode the emails do not go to the customer but when in production they work just fine.

Comment: Dan's answer below is the one you want.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can add `setter="false"` and `getter="false"` to prevent getters and setters, but you can't restrict access to the properties directly. Your best bet is put those into your constructor in the component's local scope.

```
/**
* email
* @accessors true
*/
component email output="false" hint="This is email object." {

isDevMode = false;
devModeToEmailAddress = "foo@foo.com";
devModeFromEmailAddress = "bar@foo.com";

/* properties */
property name="toEmailAddress"   type="string";
property name="fromEmailAddress" type="string";
property name="subject"          type="string";
property name="body"             type="string";
property name="attachments"      type="array";


}
```

Then, when you need to use those, just reference `variables.isDevMode` in any function to pick up the value. If you need to set those at runtime, you can set them in the `init()` method for your function. I usually do it like this:

```
component email output="false" hint="This is email object." {

    instance = {};

    /* properties */
    property name="toEmailAddress"   type="string";
    property name="fromEmailAddress" type="string";
    property name="subject"          type="string";
    property name="body"             type="string";
    property name="attachments"      type="array";


    public email function(required boolean isDevMode, required string devModeToEmailAddress, required string devModeFromEmailAddress){

        variables.Instance.isDevMode = Arguments.isDevMode;
        variables.Instance.devModeToEmailAddress = Arguments.devModeToEmailAddress;
        variables.Instance.devModeFromEmailAddress = Arguments.devModeFromEmailAddress;

    {

}
```

Then, any time I need those values I just get `variables.Instance.isDevMode`. I also create a generic `get()` method that will return the `variables.instance` so I can see what's in there.

```
public struct function get(){
    return Duplicate(variables.Instance);
}
```

But because these are in the components local variables scope, they can't be modified from outside the component.

Comment: I think you could still modify the structure by reference though. So you may want to `duplicate()` the structure before returning it.